# Invalid number of arguments PhpStorm

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a little problem with PhpStorm 2017. I get this error message even if my code is working properly:

[image]

I don't know how to deactivate this message. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try adding jquery as a library in your project. File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries then enable the global jQuery.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss in this case, I think the picture is appropriate

Comment: @mark Schultheiss my code is working ! i've done this already but it doesn't seem to work ! i still have the warning alert !

Comment: I know this isn't a solution, but have you tried using `on` to add the click handler? E.G `$('#cookie_btn').on('click',function (){})`

Comment: So "some unnoticed subtle thing" in the actual code perhaps?  Hard to tell from this post as it currently stands - be sure to post what (if anything) is before and after your code segment.  Note the picture is of value here but not the entire evidence body perhaps. - what does the "more..." show when opened?

Comment: It's just an IDE warning -- it unable to resolve `click()` method correctly. 1) Possibly because you need to reference non-minified version of jQuery (via JavaScript Libraries as bassxzerro suggested) 2) If you Ctrl+Click on `click()` -- where it will take you to?

Comment: @bassxzero it works with your solution ! i don't have this error anymore ! Is this the right solution or just a temporary fix ? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux both `.click` and `.on('click'` are valid, but I prefer the later. I can't remember why exactly, but I think you can't use `.off` on events that were added via `.click`.

Comment: @bassxzero ok perfect ! thx a lot ! i'm new to stackoverflow ! is there a way to mark this post as 'solved' ?

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux I created an answer that you can mark as "solved" or correct.

Comment: i just checked your answer ! is it good ?

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux it is. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding jquery as a library in your project. File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries then enable the global jQuery. You might need to restart your IDE.

If that doesn't work you can use the "on" syntax to add the click event handler. 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

E.G

```
$('#cookie_btn').click(function (){})
```

Becomes

```
$('#cookie_btn').on('click',function (){})
```

Answer (score 4):

I used **jQuery** instead of **$** as the warning keep showing.

[image: "jQuery" instead of "$"]

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your answer to replace them with the respective code. Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I want both the line display under 'document' and which disappear.
Can you suggest how to do with the respective code and format the code for very sample input/output properly

Comment: @TimDiekmann This image is appropriate as the point of interest is PhpStorm's highlighting, not the code itself.